# Is there I can use ANIMAL_CHOICES.RABBIT to get value in Python?

Tags: python

I have a requirement to use the data like bellow:

I am in assumption:

```
ANIMAL_CHOICES = {
    "RABBIT":"RABBIT",
    "CAMEL":"CAMEL",
}

print(ANIMAL_CHOICES["RABBIT"]) # there I can get the "RABBIT", and can see the RABBIT easily.
```

You see, I can put the `ANIMAL_CHOICES` to a single file , when I use it I can use `ANIMAL_CHOICES["RABBIT"]` to do it. I can easily know the value by its key in other files, but there is a defect, and I will go to ANIMAL_CHOICES source to see the key.

So, whether there is a more tidy method to get this effect?

I mean whether I can use `ANIMAL_CHOICES.RABBIT` to get the `"RABBIT"`?

---

**EDIT**

I mean is there other python data type we can use to get the effect? you see the Dictionary can not reach the requirement.

Comment: Since ANIMAL_CHOICES is a dict and not a class you cannot access its key `"RABBIT"` with `ANIMAL_CHOICES.RABBIT`.

Comment: @mrCarnivore Yeah, I mean is other type I can do like this?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you mean if there is another datatype other than dict where you can do it? No. Just with a class in which you specificly add each member. You cannot add new members dynamicly then.

Comment: You mean you needs autocompletion in IDE?

Comment: @IvanBryzzhin I mean whether there is a datatype I can use like `ANIMAL_CHOICES.RABBIT`. its more convenient. if in Swift language this is achievable.

Comment: @mrCarnivore how would using a class prevent from dynamically adding items to it exactly ? Unless you use slots, Python's objects are dict-based and you can dynamically add / replace / remove attributes wherever you want.

Comment: just make own class and use `__getattribute__`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Indeed. Thank you for that hint. You learn a new thing every day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a class as a namespace:

```
class AnimalChoices(object):
    RABBIT = "RABBIT"
    CAMEL = "CAMEL"

print(AnimalChoices.RABBIT)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class My_dict(dict):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return self[name]


d = My_dict({
    "RABBIT": "RABBIT",
    "CAMEL": "CAMEL",
})

print(d.RABBIT)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a class it would work:

```
class AnimalChoices:
    def __init__(self):
        self.RABBIT = 'RABBIT'
        self.CAMEL = 'CAMEL'


animal_choices = AnimalChoices()
print(animal_choices.RABBIT)
animal_choices.DOG = 'DOG'
print(animal_choices.DOG)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own animal_choices class that generates it's properties based on the keys of your data structure.

```
class animal_properties:
 def __init__(self, dictionary):
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
animal = animal_properties({"RABBIT":"RABBIT", "CAMEL":"CAMEL"})
animal.RABBIT
```